# Obj C: UIView in bottom right corner

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I want to stick a UIView in the bottom right corner of the screen, but the alignment is off. In my view did load I have...$

```
int size = 50;
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - (size + 10), self.view.frame.size.height - (size + 10), size, size);
UIView *colorView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
colorView.layer.cornerRadius = size / 2;
colorView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
colorView.backgroundColor = ColorDarkGray;
[self.view addSubview:colorView];
```

Now to me, this should be putting the view in the bottom right corner with a bit of padding. But it is completely off the screen. I have auto layout shut off, and I'm just stuck. Could someone please help me figure this out.

Comment: Comment out masktobounds

Comment: Did you check what was the value of `self.view.frame` at this point? Depending where you implemented this, it may be that `self.view` has not yet been lay out.

Comment: probably you are not using iPhone portrait mode.did you try to do it in viewWillAppear ?

Comment: Autolayout / autoresizing? What rules are applied?

Comment: viewWillAppear did it man. Thank you. Figured ViewDidLoad would be the right place but clearly not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old by now - but I stumbled over the same issue and found a solution.

Basically, if you read out the `self.view.frame` values in viewDidLoad or something similar, the layouting seems not yet to be done, so the frame is off.

Try overriding `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and set the frame there again after `[super viewWillLayoutSubviews];` - and it will work!

Please note that adding the view in `viewWillAppear` may not be called only once, so the view could be added multiple times!